# Where does git clone save downloaded files to on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, git

It's Windows 10 and git installed is v2.34.1 for Windows downloaded from http://git-scm.com.

I downloaded a zip file from https://github.com/nvpro-samples/build_all, unzipped it to a new folder, and right-clicked "Run as administrator" on the `clone_all.bat` file which run `git clone` command repeatedly. It ran with a lot of download messages, but after it finished uttering these messages, I can see no files download in the folder containing `clone_all.bat`. If I run the `clone_all.bat` file again, the messages in the console told me that "Already up to date." I guess that the first execution did save the downloaded files to somewhere but not the current directory. So, how can I figure out where `git clone` save downloaded files to on Windows? PS, I didn't see `.git` folder either.

Answer (score 2):

Without additional arguments, `git clone` will create a directory with the repository's name under the current running directory, and clone the repository into it.

Reading through the script, on each `folder` call it goes up one direcotry level (i.e., `..`) and executes a `git clone` command. I.e., when the script is done, you should have a series of directories on the same level as `build_all`, each one containing one of those demo projects, and having its own `.git` folder.

Comment: The zip file downloaded from the github repo is `build_all-master.zip`, which is in `Downloads` folder of Windows. This zip file contains `build_all-master` folder and I uncompressed it right under `Downloads`. So, after uncompression, `Downloads` contains both `build_all-master.zip` file and `build_all-master` subfolder. `clone_all.bat` file to be executed is in the `build_all-master` subfolder. According to your answer, the folders of sample projects should be immediately in `Downloads`. But there are not these sample project folders in `Downloads` after running `clone_all.bat`.

Comment: I found it, inspired by the title of command window "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe". Yes, something goes up one level, but it is "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" which runs `git clone` that goes up one level, not the batch file "clone_all.bat" in the uncompressed folder that goes up one level. So, when right clicking "Run as administrator" on the `clone_all.bat`, `git` clones the sample project folders to `C:\Windows`. :-)